# Plot function = value Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a function `f(x1,x2) = x1*x2`. That is easy enough to plot using ezsurf.

Can I plot `f(x1,x2) = x1*x2 = 1`? I want to see what specific sets of solutions look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`contour`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html):

```
z = f(x1, x2);
contour(x1, x2, z, [1 1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I think you need to start with meshgrid, then contour. Cheers.